# IMPOSSIBLE to configure your SDK Via Configure | Project Default | Project Structure | SDKs

Tags: android, sdk

Hello Installing Android Studio seems to be a nightmare !

- I've downloaded this build : android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows
- At the first execution it says that JVM is missing
- So I've installed : jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe
- Next run Now I get a message saying that I need an environnement variable to catch the JDK
- OK I set it also
- Finaly the JDK can be found.... but the nightmare is not finish
- I launch Android Studio and try to open a new Project
- Now it does not found the SDK which was suposed to come with the IDE
- OK back to Download I get : installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe (Very explicit name !!) and I install it
- I try again : still no SDK
- I keep calm I continue to follow the rules

> Your Android SDK is Missing, out of date or is missing Templates
>   You can configure your SDK Via Configure | Project Default | Project Structure | SDKs

So I try to set

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

But the IDE refuse to keep that setting

Now I give-up I need some help

Maybe let the SDK installed on Program_Files is not a good idea ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Simple Open the Android Studio.

First click on `File` menu then `Project Structure` then you will find an option to set the SDK location. Now instead of writing path simply browse then you are done.

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79599) about that earlier today.

Just start creating or importing a project from the welcome dialog. You should be prompted to supply the SDK path at that point, and (so far) that seems to stick.